# pdf document scanner for windows

Tags: windows, pdf

I am looking for a document scanner for windows 10 (for my surface tablet) to convert paper documents via camera to multipage pdf documents. Something like [Genius Scan](https://www.thegrizzlylabs.com/genius-scan/pricing/#help-deciding) but for Windows.

Requirements:

- Multipage pdf creation
- Ad Free
- No login/account required
- free or paid (but just pay once!)
- Convenient to use
- Should produce reasonable small pdf file sizes

Nice to have:

- Automatically adding an ocr layer for machine typed documents
- Automatic document detection
- Automatic perspective correction
- Adjustable output resolution

Answer (score 1):

The one which I use and highly recommend is [NAPS2](https://www.naps2.com/).

- It is open source and ad-free.
- Has OCR, Multipage pdf creation, etc.
- No login/account required.
- It produces reasonably small files.
- You can even use it to split and/or merge old files (pdfs, images) by dragging files into console, and manipulating each page.

It has not been updated for a couple of years, but it works very well.

Comment: Does this work with camera as input? For me it seems just to work with Scanners? Maybe there is a way to covert the camera to a virtual scanner device or something like that?

Comment: Not done that myself. Check the issues queue. A way to do this is take your images with camera, then drag into NAPS2 to do OCR/merge etc.

Comment: You can ask the question here: https://sourceforge.net/p/naps2/discussion/general/

Comment: Also, note that you can use something like Scan Tailor https://scantailor.org/ to clean up images, fix orientation, deskew etc.